# How to write in directory out of home?

Tags: permissions, group

I have my Apache server running in the `/srv/http/` directory. I changed the group of it to `httpadmin` and then added my user to that group. Then, I changed the permissions of that directory to `rwxrwxr-x`, which means everyone in the group `httpadmin` should be able to write in that directory, right?

Yet, I can't create files in it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After changing your group, you have to log out and log in again for your new group assignment to be active. You can either log out or

Answer (score 0):

check your identity with `id | grep httpadmin || echo check permissions.` command. If you have any output here, you should add yourself to this group. You can use `pw`, `usermod` or any same command and then login your system again.

Next point you should check is permissions which written files have. At my home server I use sticky group to doesn't matter about default group I write and permission umask I have.